# Object-like macro expansion does more than just substituting?

Tags: c++, macos, string-literals

I always thought `object-like macro-expansion` is just plain substitution of the preprocessor. However, the following code snippet doesn't work. I expected it to expand to the second example. But it didn't..

```
#define R "x"

auto main() -> int {

  const char* s = R"y"; // ill-formed raw string literal
  const char* s2 = "x""y"; // a raw string literal followed by a normal string literal

  return 0;
}
```

With a miraculous space it just works..

```
const char* s = R "y";
```

Is this some lexical analysis thing? And if so, what translation phase does it happen in?
Thanks.

Comment: A preprocessor works with tokens. `R"y"` is a single token, not recognized by a preprocessor.

Comment: @273K Ah okay that makes sense. So macro expansion is also just matching tokens?

Comment: here is a list of all the tokens that the pre-processor recognizes https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#nt:preprocessing-token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw string literals were introduced in C++11 and the following applies only since C++11. Before C++11 all of your examples would have been well-formed. This is an intentionally backwards-incompatible change made with C++11.

---

A raw string literal has, for example, the following form

```
R"END(this is a "raw" string literal)END"
```

which is equivalent to the normal string literal `"this is a \"raw\" string literal"`.

The `END` can be any arbitrary, possibly empty, character sequence (excluding some characters and limited in length) marking the end of the literal and before `R` there may be an encoding prefix like `L`. In any case the `(` and `)` are not optional. They are part of the syntax for a string literal.

Macro substitution happens in the translation phase 4, which is after forming of preprocessing tokens in phase 3.

A raw string literal, like any other literal, is a single preprocessing token.

During phase 3 preprocessing tokens are formed one-by-one by successively inspecting characters in the input sequence. When starting to parse a new token and the next characters are `R"`, optionally prefixed by a possible encoding prefix for a raw string, then the token is always assumed to be a raw string literal and *must* be valid according to the grammar I described above. If it isn't valid raw string literal, then the program is ill-formed. The compiler will never parse the `R` as a separate token followed by a normal string literal. This is an exception in the lexing rule made specifically for raw string literals.

Because this happens before any macro substitution in phase 4, `#define R "x"` isn't relevant at all and `R"y"` is an ill-formed raw string literal, because it doesn't have the `(` and `)` required by the grammar, causing already phase 3 to fail.

In `"x""y"` there is no raw string literal, because there is no `R"`. These are two normal string literals `"x"` and `"y"`.

`R "y"` is not ill-formed, because these are two tokens `R` and `"y"`. A whitespace always separates tokens (except inside the quotes of string/character literals). `R` will be substituted with `"x"` in phase 4 and there is no problem.